# Issues with binary file c++ android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, rsa

I am trying to port a windows c++ project and i am having trouble with the following code:

```
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_KEY_DATA), _T("KEY_DATA"));
pBuffer = (LPBYTE)LockResource(LoadResource(hModule, hResource));
cbBuffer = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
Keystore.Initialize(pBuffer, cbBuffer);
```

In c++ NDK i opted to define the contents of the binary file as a BYTE array, this is what i have:

```
BYTE key_bytes[] = { 0x06,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x4B,0x00,0x00,0x41,0x42,0x4A,0x4C,0x15,0x96,0x23,0x62,0x5F,...};
```

And how i implement the windows c++ code in NDK:

```
    int arraySize = sizeof(key_bytes) / sizeof(key_bytes[0]);
    LPBYTE pBuffer = &key_bytes[0];
    DWORD cbBuffer = arraySize;
    Keystore.Initialize(pBuffer, cbBuffer);
```

The problem is that the RSACypher method I use fails on the NDK implementation with a segmentation exception.

when inspecting the values of pBuffer during debugging in both the windows and NDK implementation this is what I get:
Windows = "\x6\x2"
NDK = "\006\002"

I believe the cause of the exception might be related to this. I am a novice c++ developer and have no idea how to make the NDK pBuffer look like the Windows pBuffer variable. pBuffer is type LPBYTE.

Can anybody help me with this, please?

As requested:
Windows Variables and values:

```
LPBYTE pBuffer = 0x0fd41518 "\x6\x2"
DWORD cbBuffer = 3120
```

Android NDK variables and values:

```
LPBYTE pBuffer = 0x8a8f5004 <key_bytes> "\006\002"
DWORD cbBuffer = 3120
```

The windows dll project functions correctly but the android .so project gives a segmentation fault exception on the following line in the RSA.cpp file:

```
int cinfo = cryptInfo->ctxPKC.keySizeBits;
```

Containing Function:

```
int rsaCypher(void *ptr, BYTE *buffer, int noBytes)
```

{

```
CRYPT_INFO *cryptInfo = (CRYPT_INFO *)ptr;
BN_CTX *bnCTX;
BIGNUM *n;
int cinfo = cryptInfo->ctxPKC.keySizeBits;
int length = bitsToBytes(cinfo);
int i, status = CRYPT_OK;

if (noBytes != length || length == 0)
    return -2;      // length error

                    /* Make sure we're not being fed suspiciously short data quantities */
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    if (buffer[i])
        break;
if (length - i < 56)
    return(CRYPT_ERROR_BADDATA);

if ((bnCTX = BN_CTX_new()) == NULL)
    return(CRYPT_ERROR_MEMORY);

/* Move the data from the buffer into a bignum, perform the modexp, and
move the result back into the buffer.  Since the bignum code performs
leading-zero truncation, we have to adjust where we copy the result to
in the buffer to take into account extra zero bytes which aren't
extracted from the bignum */
n = BN_new();
BN_bin2bn(buffer, length, n);
zeroise(buffer, length);    /* Clear buffer while data is in bignum */
BN_mod_exp_mont(n, n, cryptInfo->ctxPKC.rsaParam_e,
    cryptInfo->ctxPKC.rsaParam_n, bnCTX,
    cryptInfo->ctxPKC.rsaParam_mont_n);
BN_bn2bin(n, buffer + (length - BN_num_bytes(n)));
BN_clear_free(n);

BN_CTX_free(bnCTX);

return((status == -1) ? CRYPT_ERROR_FAILED : status);
```

}

After investigation i see the *ptr variable value is 0x0. I believe this is causing the segmentation fault. In the windows library it contains a valid pointer value.

The only difference i could find between the two projects is the discrepancy between the pBuffer value in the windows project and the pBuffer value in the NDK project.

WIndows project vs2017
WIndows SDK 10
Build tools 2017(141)

NDK project vs2017 Xamarin
NDK13b
clang 3.8 build tools

Update:
I believe the root cause is the byte array encoding. It is supposed to be UTF-16BE but VS Xamarin with clang3.8 supports UTF-8. Does anybody know how to copy the raw bytes from to a UTF-16BE string in android NDK13c ?

Comment: New array size seems to be off by 1.

Comment: tried to do it without the +1 in an attempt to solve the segmentation exception. I read that it might be caused when the array is too small.

Comment: `int arraySize = sizeof(pBuffer) / sizeof(pBuffer[0]);
cbBuffer = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
Keystore.Initialize(pBuffer, cbBuffer);` arraySize is not used. What is the type of cbBuffer? Please tell all values of your int variables and the sizeof operators. For both cases. Compare.

Comment: `this is what I get: Windows = "\x6\x2" NDK = "\006\002"` Please comment. Is it ok or not?

Comment: variables: DWORD cbBuffer, LPBYTE pBuffer. the windows "\x6\x2" is correct. I believe the NDK "\006\002" is not.

Comment: in the windows snippet, the arraySize and byteSize variables was used for troubleshooting the cause of the exception in the NDK dynamic library

Comment: Values Windows : cbBuffer = 3120 pBuffer = 0x0fd41518 "\x6\x2"

Comment: Values NDK = cbBuffer = 3120   LPBYTE pBuffer = (LPBYTE)&key_bytes[0];

Comment: Values pBuffer = 0x8a8f5004 <key_bytes> "\006\002"